# Plotting from a data file - dots on a figure are not in the exact positions

Tags: gnuplot

My data file Im using for plotting:

```
0.005200 1
0.005333 2
0.005333 3
0.005333 4
0.005333 5
0.005467 6
0.005467 7
0.005467 8
```

My GNUplot script used for plotting:

```
#!/usr/bin/gnuplot

set xlabel "test"
set ylabel "value"
set grid ytics lt 0 lw 1 lc rgb "#bbbbbb"
set grid xtics lt 0 lw 1 lc rgb "#bbbbbb"
set autoscale
set terminal postscript portrait enhanced color dashed lw 1 'Helvetica' 14
set style line 2 lc rgb 'red' pt 7   # circle
set output 'test.eps'
plot 'data.txt' using 2:1 with points ls 2 title "time series plot"
```

Output image generated with GNUplot:

[image]

As you see in the data file I posted, value for the second, third, fourth and the fifth test is `0.005333`. (As well as for the sixth, seventh and eighth  test - there is a value of `0.005467`).

But you can't see that on a figure - take a look at it. For the second, third, fourth and the fifth test the value on the figure is in somewhere between the `0.0053` and `0.00535` and I need the dots to be in the EXACT position on figure as its on the text file.

I have so much such files, is there any "portable" way to use it for every file I have?

Answer (score 1):

The points are of course in the correct position. Add

```
set ytics add (0.005333, 0.005467)
```

to your script to see this:

[image]

Comment: Thanks! But I have lots of such files ... Is there any simple method to add the whole first column from my datafile as yticks?

Comment: You could use `plot 'data.txt' using 2:1:ytic(1) with points`, but that uses only the data points as ytics and not the automatic ones.